# Finding semantic similarity and relations between different words

Tags: nlp, semantics, wordnet, semantic-analysis

I am working on a project which involves computation of relatedness between different concepts.

Examples:
"landing" - related to: "to arrive; to come" and "land",
"telephone" - related to: "electronic; electricity" and "to talk; to communicate",
"movie" - related to: "to move; to change" and "picture; image"
, and so on.

I have checked the WordNet framework and WordNet::Similarity Perl module, but in some cases they are not usable, especially in cases where I need to connect nouns with verbs (for example a noun "dog" and a verb "to bark"). Also, WordNet organizes all synsets in hierarchical structure (ex: computer -> machine -> device -> instrumentation), and this is not that I really need in my project (of course, I may be wrong).

The question is - which framework or database, what approach should I use to solve the problem? Where do I start?

It would be really helpful if you could give me some advice.

Comment: You need to organize similarity ,relations and semantics of your need. I  think relation between "landing" and "land" and relation between "landing" and "to arrive" are relations of different semantics. You may need framework which can handle memantics and relations among words.

Comment: You should take a shot at exploiting the "derivationally related forms" in WordNet for relating nouns to verbs. But ... the *real* (i.e. research'y) way to understand concept relatedness is by modeling words using their distributional similarity over a large dataset.

Answer (score 3):

word2vec embeddings might do a good job on your task.  It gives a much softer notion of similarity than wordnet.  You can get some pre-trained embeddings linked from here https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/ .